# The Theographer's Journal - Discover an ancient secret and finish the work of a chronicler of the gods

Tags: riddle

**This is a riddle worded as a historical excerpt for the sake of the decipherer's entertainment.**

Excerpt from the journal of Aulete of Hal-Saflieni, chronicler of the gods:

One curious case is that of the goddess of the high and the deep. After the culture's patriarch god created the universe, it seems that the new universe in turn created this diety itself. Angered that his creations made their own god, the patriarch refuses to allow her into the heavens. Unable to ascend, she is said to reside in the worship houses of sky, earth, and sea. The goddess of all cathedrals, all temples, and all mosques, songs to every diety are sung to her glory first. Her magical cloak makes her invisible, hidden from the creator, but practitioners insist that even the most faithless believe in her.

Intense study will follow, but with caution. The elders say that those who worship too intensely can diminish their connection to the goddess permanently. In some extreme cases, severe pain and disorientation have occurred.

Aulete died without ever elaborating on the subject. Archeologists haven't found anything either. Can you figure out the name of the goddess for the sake of preserving history and prove conclusively to the archeological community that you're correct?

Comment: You may find that [puzzles are off-topic on Puzzling.SE](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/puzzling-se-where-we-hate-fun-its-time-to-disallow-challenge-questions?cb=1), unfortunately :-/

Comment: @Travis, mods have decreed that (regardless of what the ocmmunity thinks) solving puzzles is now off-topic for puzzling.SE: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/puzzling-se-where-we-hate-fun-its-time-to-disallow-challenge-questions We're looking at other options, see http://puzzling.xyz/

Comment: Travis, are you going to try and stick it out till the bitter end? Be careful, mods can be dangerous! :-)

Comment: Just heard the news. Still trying to work this out in my head. How will Puzzles SE stay open if it's only the three people globally that are really into puzzle theory?

Comment: Just for future reference, and anyone who hasn't heard already, it appears that puzzles are back on-topic. We're all OK :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She represents

> Sound.

Explanations:

`the high and the deep`:

> A sound or note can be described as high or deep.

`After the culture's patriarch god created the universe, it seems that the new universe in turn created this deity itself.`

> Sound can only happen after something is around to make it.

`Angered that his creations made their own god, the patriarch refuses to allow her into the heavens. Unable to ascend, she is said to reside in the worship houses of sky, earth, and sea.`

> There is no sound in space. Gas, liquids, and solids can all be transmission mediums for sound.

`The goddess of all cathedrals, all temples, and all mosques, songs to every deity are sung to her glory first.`

> All songs must make sound, and any religious congregation makes noise of some sort.

`Her magical cloak makes her invisible, hidden from the creator, but practitioners insist that even the most faithless believe in her.`

> Sound is not visible, but everyone believes in it.

`The elders say that those who worship too intensely can diminish their connection to the goddess permanently. In some extreme cases, severe pain and disorientation have occurred.`

> Listening to loud sounds damages hearing and can cause pain/disorientation.

Comment: Well done. I'll add that the name is a pair of clues as well. An aulete is a player of an aulos, an ancient clarinet. Hal-Saflieni is the site of an ancient resonance chamber.

Answer (score 4):

The goddess is

> Air

Some explanations:

`the patriarch refuses to allow her into the heavens. Unable to ascend, she is said to reside in the worship houses of sky, earth, and sea.`

> Gravity holds the air below a certain altitude, so it is held close to the earth, sky, and sea.

`songs to every diety are sung to her glory first.`

> Before you can sing, you have to take in a breath of air.

`The elders say that those who worship too intensely can diminish their connection to the goddess permanently. In some extreme cases, severe pain and disorientation have occurred.`

> You can become dizzy, pass out, or even die, if you hold air in your lungs for too long.

Comment: Well reasoned, but incorrect. There are almost a dozen clues that could be explained, though a quarter or so are archaic enough that they'll probably not be figured out.